# IPtables issues - Assistance appreciated

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, iptables

I am trying to make a firewall for my raspberry pi. The rules that I want are

1. Allow incoming SSH - this works
2. Allow outgoing ssh - this does NOT work and is my main issue
3. Allow incoming and outgoing VNC - currently this semi-works where I am able to connect but I can't do any actions. Not really a priority
4. Allow outgoing https - I can visit a website but I think I need to add another line for DNS for this to work properly on boot.
5. Allow outgoing emails - this works
6. Allow outgoing pings and get a reply - this works
7. Drop everything else - Guessing this works because I can't make outgoing SSH so I believe the issue is in my rule.

I know my ssh works in general as without the firewall loaded I can make an outgoing SSH from one pi to another.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    #Flush all rules
    iptables -F

    #Allow incoming and outgoing SSH
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

    #Allow VNC sessions
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.10.1,192.168.0.150 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5900:5905,6000:6005 -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.1,192.168.0.150 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --sports 5900:5905,6000:6005 -j ACCEPT

    #Accept only incoming etstablished and allow new or established outgoing
    sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

    #Accept port 587 for email
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 587 -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT

    #Allow ping requests to go out and get a reply
    sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

    #Drop all other packets and protocols
    sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
    sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
    sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: The issue is your source port being `22`. The source port refers to the local port on your machine. Your machine will not use port `22` to connect to a remote SSH server.

Comment: @confetti so what exactly should I do then?

Comment: Simply use --dport 22. This will allow every outgoing connection to a destination port of 22.

Comment: As for your other issues, have you tried `-m conntrack --ctstate` like you did with the SSH rules instead of `-m state --state`?

Comment: @confetti No I have not tried adding that but I can, i will focus on them after I resolve this SSH issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with the SSH line is that you're trying to allow source port `22` from your local machine. However, when you connect to a remote SSH server your machine does not use port 22 for this. It's using a random port, usually in the higher port range. This makes sense because if it were to use port 22 for outgoing SSH connections, you could only connect to one SSH server at a time.

In order to fix this, the most simple way is to use `--dport` instead of `--sport`, allowing every connection that has a destination port of `22` (ssh).

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Please note that you have to **add** this line instead of replacing it, as @bcs78 pointed out in the comments.

It's also generally a bad idea to block traffic for the internal loopback connection. Some programs rely on this connection and won't work properly without it. Add this to the beginning of your script:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi, I tried changing the out as you said, and now I am able to make the outgoing connection. However my incoming connections don't work now.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change something else? I don't see how an OUTPUT rule would affect an INPUT rule at all. Do you see any change at all? Also add a `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` to the beginning of your script. Blocking the loopback interface is generally a bad idea and might result in several programs not working properly anymore.

Comment: The incoming SSH connection cannot be established because the outgoing rule that allows packets from port 22 (including the acknowledge packets) has been removed. So you have to have an ACCEPT rule in OUTGOING chain which allows outgoing packets from SOURCE port 22 (as it is in your original config). The ACCEPT rule in OUTGOING chain to DESTINATION port 22 should be an additional rule and not a replacement.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add, once per chain, a catch-all *stateful* rule that will simplify most other rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -F

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Plus usual `lo` interface rule to allow all local services, remove it if you think it's really not needed:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Now you don't have to duplicate your other rules (I'm leaving the `NEW` state when it was there, even if it isn't very useful and wasn't consistently present):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.10.1 -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5900:5905,6000:6005 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.150 -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5900:5905,6000:6005 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

Everything is taken care of by the first two rules, no need to duplicate every rule, and now the flow's initial direction is clear: `INPUT` or `OUTPUT`, only once. So it makes more clear that the `--sport 22` for SSH wasn't helping for the outgoing case (`--dport 22` is needed). `RELATED` would have been useful if there were `udp` rules for related `icmp` error replies. In this setting it might not be needed.